# How to append an index column to a spark data frame using spark streaming in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using something like this:

```
df.withColumn("idx", monotonically_increasing_id())
```

But I get an exception as it is NOT SUPPORTED:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Expression(s): monotonically_increasing_id() is not supported with streaming DataFrames/Datasets;;

at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.checkForStreaming(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:143)
at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager.createQuery(StreamingQueryManager.scala:250)
at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager.startQuery(StreamingQueryManager.scala:316)
```

Any ideas how to add an index or row number column to **spark streaming** dataframe in scala?

Full stacktrace: https://justpaste.it/5bdqr

Answer (score 1):

There are a few operations that cannot exists anywhere in a streaming plan of Spark Streaming, unfortunately including `monotonically_increasing_id()`. Double check for this fact `transformed1` is failing with the error as in your question, [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/51ebcd95a5f7e377245f302a91e90f9b3db9953e/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala#L193) is a reference on this check in Spark source code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 

val df = Seq(("one", 1), ("two", 2)).toDF("foo", "bar")
val schema = df.schema
df.write.parquet("/tmp/out")
val input = spark.readStream.format("parquet").schema(schema).load("/tmp/out")

val transformed1 = input.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
transformed1.writeStream.format("parquet").option("format", "append") .option("path", "/tmp/out2") .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/checkpoint_path").outputMode("append").start()

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val windowSpecRowNum = Window.partitionBy("foo").orderBy("foo")

val transformed2 = input.withColumn("row_num", row_number.over(windowSpecRowNum))
transformed2.writeStream.format("parquet").option("format", "append").option("path", "/tmp/out2").option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/checkpoint_path").outputMode("append").start()
```

Also I tried to add indexing with `Window` over a column in DF - `transformed2` in the snapshot above - it also failed, but with a different [error](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/51ebcd95a5f7e377245f302a91e90f9b3db9953e/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala#L371)):

> "Non-time-based windows are not supported on streaming
> DataFrames/Datasets"

All unsupported operator checks for Spark Streaming you can find [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/51ebcd95a5f7e377245f302a91e90f9b3db9953e/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala#L203) - seems like the traditional ways of adding an index column in Spark Batch don't work in Spark Streaming.